# Stopping busybox's `httpd`

Tags: busybox, web-server

I just found that busybox has `httpd`. I started it, and now I don't know how to stop it without rebooting. My busybox version is Stephen Ericson, 1.26.2

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT
Here is the output of `ps`

angler:/ $ su
angler:/ # ps

```
USER      PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS   WCHAN              PC  NAME
root      1     0     11092  1424  SyS_epoll_ 00005134e0 S /init
root      2     0     0      0       kthreadd 0000000000 S kthreadd
root      3     2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S ksoftirqd/0
root      5     2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/0:0H
root      6     2     0      0     msm_mpm_wo 0000000000 D kworker/u16:0
root      7     2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S migration/0
root      8     2     0      0     rcu_gp_kth 0000000000 S rcu_preempt
root      9     2     0      0     rcu_gp_kth 0000000000 S rcu_bh
root      10    2     0      0     rcu_gp_kth 0000000000 S rcu_schedroot      11    2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S migration/1
root      12    2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S ksoftirqd/1
root      14    2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/1:0H
root      15    2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S migration/2
root      16    2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S ksoftirqd/2
root      18    2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/2:0H
root      19    2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S migration/3
root      20    2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S ksoftirqd/3
root      22    2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/3:0H
root      23    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S khelper
root      24    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S netns
root      25    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S perf
root      30    2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/1:1H
root      31    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S smd_channel_clo
root      32    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S smsm_cb_wq
root      34    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S deferwq
root      35    2     0      0     msm_rpm_sm 0000000000 D kworker/u17:0
root      36    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S rpm-smd
root      38    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/48-cpr
root      39    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/51-cpr
root      40    2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S migration/4
root      41    2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S ksoftirqd/4
root      42    2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/4:0
root      43    2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/4:0H
root      44    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S mpm
root      46    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S writebackroot      47    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S bioset
root      48    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S crypto
root      49    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S kblockd
root      50    2     0      0     hub_thread 0000000000 S khubd
root      51    2     0      0     ion_heap_d 0000000000 S system
root      52    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ipa_power_mgmt
root      53    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S sps_ipa_power_m
root      54    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ipawq14
root      55    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S iparepwq14
root      56    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ipawq43
root      57    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S iparepwq43
root      58    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ipawq13
root      59    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S iparepwq13
root      60    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ipa_rm_wqroot      61    2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ipa_interrupt_w
root      62    2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/4:1H
root      64    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/261-msm_iom
root      65    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/263-msm_iom
root      66    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/261-msm_iom
root      67    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/263-msm_iom
root      68    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/261-msm_iom
root      69    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/263-msm_iom
root      70    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/261-msm_iom
root      71    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/263-msm_iom
root      72    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/261-msm_iom
root      73    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/263-msm_iom
root      74    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/261-msm_iom
root      75    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/263-msm_iom
root      76    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/261-msm_iom
root      77    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/263-msm_iom
root      78    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/102-msm_iom
root      79    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/102-msm_iom
root      80    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/102-msm_iom
root      81    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/102-msm_iom
root      82    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/74-msm_iomm
root      83    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/75-msm_iomm
root      84    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/75-msm_iomm
root      85    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/75-msm_iomm
root      86    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/75-msm_iomm
root      87    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/273-msm_iom
root      88    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/273-msm_iom
root      89    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/272-msm_iom
root      90    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/97-msm_iomm
root      91    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/97-msm_iomm
root      92    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/97-msm_iomm
root      93    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/350-msm_iom
root      94    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/350-msm_iom
root      95    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/350-msm_iom
root      96    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/298-msm_iom
root      97    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/298-msm_iom
root      98    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/298-msm_iom
root      99    2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/79-msm_iomm
root      100   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/78-msm_iomm
root      101   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/78-msm_iomm
root      102   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S devfreq_wq
root      103   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S cfg80211
root      104   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/15-bcl_vbat
root      105   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/460-bcl_iba
root      106   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S rpciod
root      129   2     0      0         kswapd 0000000000 S kswapd0
root      130   2     0      0     ksm_scan_t 0000000000 S ksmd
root      131   2     0      0     fsnotify_m 0000000000 S fsnotify_mark
root      132   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S nfsiod
root      152   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ad_calc_wq
root      153   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S rot_commit_work
root      154   2     0      0     dsi_event_ 0000000000 D mdss_dsi_event
root      155   2     0      0     kthread_wo 0000000000 S vsync_retire_wo
root      156   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S apr_driver
root      157   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S pil_vote_wq
root      158   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S shm_svc
root      159   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S qmi_hndl0000000
root      160   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S msm_ipc_router
root      161   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S k_hsuart
root      162   2     0      0     kthread_wo 0000000000 S msm_serial_hs_0
root      163   2     0      0     kthread_wo 0000000000 S msm_serial_hs_0
root      164   2     0      0     add_hwgene 0000000000 S hwrng
root      165   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S diag_real_time_
root      166   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S diag_modem_data
root      167   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S diag_lpass_data
root      168   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S diag_wcnss_data
root      169   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S diag_sensors_da
root      170   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S diag_wq
root      171   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S DIAG_USB_diag
root      172   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S diag_cntl_wq
root      173   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S diag_dci_wq
root      174   2     0      0     kthread_wo 0000000000 S kgsl_worker_thr
root      175   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S kgsl-3d0
root      176   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S kgsl-events
root      177   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S governor_msm_ad
root      178   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S kgsl_devfreq_wq
root      199   2     0      0     kthread_wo 0000000000 S spi5
root      200   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S usbnet
root      201   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S sharedmem_qmi_w
root      202   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S qmi_hndl0000000
root      204   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/212-msm_dwc
root      205   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S k_gserialroot      206   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S uether
root      209   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S dsx_rebuild_wor
root      210   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S dsx_exp_workque
root      211   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S s2wiwq
root      212   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S dt2wiwq
root      213   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/502-fpc1020
root      216   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S fwu_workqueue
root      217   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S msm_cpp_workque
root      219   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/495-batt-mi
root      220   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/504-synapti
root      245   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S dm_bufio_cache
root      246   2     0      0     cpufreq_in 0000000000 S cfinteractive
root      247   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/170-f982490
root      249   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/253-f98a490
root      251   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/499-qpnp_wl
root      252   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S binder
root      253   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/603-nanohub
root      254   2     0      0     nanohub_kt 0000000000 S nanohub
root      255   2     0      0     mmc_queue_ 0000000000 S mmcqd/0
root      256   2     0      0     mmc_queue_ 0000000000 S mmcqd/0rpmb
root      257   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S usb_bam_wq
root      258   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/500-qpnp_sc
root      259   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/224-spdm_bw
root      260   2     0      0     rfcomm_run 0000000000 S krfcommd
root      261   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/609-adsp
root      262   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/641-modem
root      264   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S msm_vidc_worker
root      265   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S pm_workerq_venu
root      267   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/464-chg-err
root      268   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/9-chg-taper
root      269   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/10-chg-tcc-
root      270   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/8-chg-rechg
root      271   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/468-chg-p2f
root      272   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/469-batt-ho
root      273   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/11-batt-war
root      274   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/13-batt-coo
root      275   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/12-batt-col
root      276   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/7-batt-miss
root      277   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/470-batt-lo
root      278   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/1-usbin-uv
root      279   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/2-usbin-ov
root      280   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/3-usbin-src
root      281   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/4-otg-fail
root      282   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/5-otg-oc
root      283   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/6-aicl-done
root      284   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/473-dcin-uv
root      285   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/475-power-o
root      286   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/476-temp-sh
root      287   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/477-safety-
root      293   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S rq_stats
root      294   2     0      0     events_not 0000000000 S msm_perf:events
root      295   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S sb-1
root      296   2     0      0     ngd_slim_r 0000000000 D ngd_rx_thread1
root      297   2     0      0     ngd_notify 0000000000 D ngd_notify_sl1
root      298   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S k_bam_data
root      299   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S f_mtp
root      300   2     0      0     sleep_thre 0000000000 S file-storage
root      301   2     0      0     do_samplin 0000000000 D msm-core:sampli
root      302   2     0      0     do_hotplug 0000000000 S msm_thermal:hot
root      303   2     0      0     do_freq_mi 0000000000 S msm_thermal:fre
root      304   2     0      0     do_thermal 0000000000 S msm_thermal:the
root      314   2     0      0     boost_mig_ 0000000000 S boost_sync/0
root      315   2     0      0     boost_mig_ 0000000000 S boost_sync/1
root      316   2     0      0     boost_mig_ 0000000000 S boost_sync/2
root      317   2     0      0     boost_mig_ 0000000000 S boost_sync/3
root      318   2     0      0     boost_mig_ 0000000000 S boost_sync/4
root      319   2     0      0     boost_mig_ 0000000000 S boost_sync/5
root      320   2     0      0     boost_mig_ 0000000000 S boost_sync/6
root      321   2     0      0     boost_mig_ 0000000000 S boost_sync/7
root      322   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ipa_A7_svc
root      323   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S qmi_hndl0000000
root      324   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S clnt_req
root      326   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S clnt_resproot      327   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S clnt_req
root      328   2     0      0     down_inter 0000000000 S wl_event_handle
root      329   2     0      0     down_inter 0000000000 S dhd_watchdog_th
root      330   1     6340   1116  do_sys_pol 0000513510 S /sbin/ueventd
root      333   2     0      0     kjournald2 0000000000 S jbd2/mmcblk0p43
root      334   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ext4-rsv-conver
root      335   2     0      0     kjournald2 0000000000 S jbd2/mmcblk0p37
root      336   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ext4-rsv-conver
root      337   2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/0:1H
root      341   2     0      0     kjournald2 0000000000 S jbd2/mmcblk0p38
root      342   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ext4-rsv-conver
root      343   2     0      0     kjournald2 0000000000 S jbd2/mmcblk0p32
root      344   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ext4-rsv-conver
root      351   2     0      0     kauditd_th 0000000000 S kauditd
root      364   1     5428   984   skb_recv_d 00f056571c S /system/bin/debuggerd
root      365   1     10788  1120  skb_recv_d 7b07f85cf4 S /system/bin/debuggerd64
root      366   1     52052  1932  hrtimer_na 7e546be744 S /system/bin/vold
root      368   365   10532  12    __skb_recv 7b07f8684c S debuggerd64:signaller
root      369   364   5172   8     __skb_recv 00f0566950 S debuggerd:signaller
root      388   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S IPCRTR
root      389   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S adsp_IPCRTR
root      392   1     51644  648   SyS_epoll_ 00004a6e78 S /sbin/healthd
root      393   1     18940  1264  do_sigtime 7a6f6bef34 S /vendor/bin/pm-service
root      395   1     9380   1412  do_sys_pol 7ac0c16e74 S /vendor/bin/msm_irqbalance
root      396   1     9428   1508  SyS_epoll_ 71c561ad54 S /system/bin/lmkd
root      406   2     0      0     kthread_wo 0000000000 S msm_slim_qmi_cl
root      407   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S qmi_hndl0000000
root      419   2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/449-wcd9xxx
root      439   2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S migration/5
root      440   2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S ksoftirqd/5
root      441   2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/5:0
root      442   2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/5:0H
root      443   2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S migration/6
root      444   2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S ksoftirqd/6
root      445   2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/6:0
root      446   2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/6:0H
root      447   2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S migration/7
root      448   2     0      0     smpboot_th 0000000000 S ksoftirqd/7
root      450   2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/7:0H
root      451   2     0      0     msm_rpm_wa 0000000000 D irq/215-fc38800
root      455   1     16132  1248  hrtimer_na 7da6c9b744 S /vendor/bin/pm-proxy
root      459   1     8040   1096  skb_recv_d 7ced8d4cf4 S /system/xbin/su
root      470   2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/7:1
root      493   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S kdmflush
root      497   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S bioset
root      498   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S kcryptd_io
root      499   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S kcryptd
root      500   2     0      0     dmcrypt_wr 0000000000 S dmcrypt_write
root      501   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S bioset
root      503   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S IPCRTR
root      504   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S modem_IPCRTR
root      514   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S qmi_hndl0000000
root      521   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S qmi_hndl0000000
root      526   2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/2:1H
root      527   2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/u17:10
root      530   2     0      0     kjournald2 0000000000 S jbd2/dm-0-8
root      531   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ext4-rsv-conver
root      540   1     76440  1348  SyS_rt_sig 78d3793f1c S /vendor/bin/thermal-engine
root      542   1     18652  964   futex_wait 73a270fe70 S /vendor/bin/perfd
root      547   1     14208  1304  futex_wait 7a60484e70 S /vendor/bin/oem_qmi_server
root      549   1     2158852 45060 do_sys_pol 72f4d60e74 S zygote64root      550   1     1592584 36712 do_sys_pol 00ef9c39a8 S zygote
drm       553   1     15168  2148  binder_thr 00f0fe1900 S /system/bin/drmserver
root      554   1     10336  1864  unix_strea 71e8db884c S /system/bin/installd
root      562   1     34456  4608  binder_thr 7f1ae08e44 S /system/bin/netd
root      564   2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/3:1H
gps       566   1     9168   1120  SyS_rt_sig 7ae9892f1c S /vendor/bin/loc_launcher
camera    567   1     120240 10980  do_select 00f4b30a00 S /vendor/bin/mm-qcamera-daemon
root      581   2     0      0     notify_use 0000000000 S wrkld_notify
gps       594   566   78224  2740  do_sys_pol 7955f17e74 S /vendor/bin/slim_daemon
root      769   2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/0:2
root      897   2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/u17:1
root      980   2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/3:2
root      986   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S ipawq44
root      987   2     0      0     rescuer_th 0000000000 S iparepwq44
root      1052  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/1:0
root      1118  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/u17:3
root      1119  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/u17:5
root      1173  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/2:2
root      1175  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/0:0
root      1228  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/3:4
root      1240  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/1:2
root      1259  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/u16:2
root      1266  2     0      0     __mdss_fb_ 0000000000 D mdss_fb0
shell     1284  1     17772  704   do_sys_pol 00004e0dc0 S /sbin/adbd
shell     1345  1284  8180   1476  SyS_rt_sig 79643c0f1c S /system/bin/sh
shell     1349  1345  8180   1480  SyS_rt_sig 7b9f819f1c S sh
shell     1351  1349  1478840 53496 SyS_epoll_ 00f4cbe7bc S /system/bin/app_process32
u0_a197   1381  550   1103676 70324 SyS_epoll_ 00ef9c37bc S com.koushikdutta.vysor
root      1437  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/u16:3
root      1465  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/5:1
root      1468  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/6:2
root      1609  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/1:3
u0_a64    1633  549   1578580 31596 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.android.terminal
u0_a48    1655  549   2257900 48508 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.wifikill.techbrain
u0_a0     1768  549   1587532 44324 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S android.process.acore
u0_a132   1792  550   1099944 57348          0 00ef9c3eb4 R yarolegovich.materialterminal
u0_a132   1818  1792  8180   1660  SyS_rt_sig 70d8a05f1c S /system/bin/sh
u0_a132   1856  1818  8040   1432     do_wait 7dc6007e4c S su
u0_a132   1857  1856  10360  560   n_tty_read 7dc600784c R su
root      1859  1     8296   260      do_wait 7ced8d5e4c S /system/xbin/su
root      1862  1859  8296   280      do_wait 7ced8d5e4c S /system/xbin/su
root      1863  1862  9312   488      do_wait 7ced8d5e4c S /system/xbin/su
root      1864  1863  8180   1712  SyS_rt_sig 757c9f7f1c S sh
root      1870  1864  9696   1704           0 7e85e2384c R ps
wifi      3073  1     14020  3108   do_select 725b791e8c S /system/bin/wpa_supplicant
u0_a69    3076  549   1655992 76788 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.android.inputmethod.latin
u0_a36    3085  549   1768496 125072 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.android.systemui
media_rw  3103  366   0      0        do_exit 0000000000 Z sdcard
u0_a1     3248  549   1577216 32608 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S org.cyanogenmod.cmaudio.service
radio     3326  549   1631248 56140 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.android.phone
u0_a81    5046  549   1577692 34208 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.google.android.ext.services
u0_a225   5090  549   1589780 44324 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S de.markusfisch.android.shadereditor
u0_a72    5127  549   1708852 109780 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.google.android.gms.persistent
u0_a85    5168  549   2294788 42772 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor
u0_a33    5183  549   1577104 32704 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S org.cyanogenmod.weatherservice
system    5197  549   1585304 37168 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.quicinc.cne.CNEService
u0_a20    5209  549   1576540 32076 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S org.omnirom.omniswitch
nfc       5224  549   1607496 47612 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.android.nfc
u0_a65    5265  549   1576524 31808 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.android.smspush
u0_a58    5377  549   1679712 148664 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.cyanogenport.trebuchet
clat      5497  562   50404  43536 hrtimer_na 7912113744 S clatd-rmnet_data7
u0_a72    6259  549   2530608 180712 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.google.android.gms
u0_a114   6335  550   1776976 67848 SyS_epoll_ 00ef9c37bc S com.lbe.parallel.intl:mdserver
u0_a59    6718  549   1576640 33124 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S org.cyanogenmod.profiles
u0_a114   6937  6335  228    4     inotify_re 0000009a4c S parallel.monitor
u0_a188   7145  549   1591428 41296 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.android.email
u0_a85    7719  549   2424232 109752 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
radio     8054  549   1577588 32740 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.qualcomm.qcrilmsgtunnel
u0_a185   8091  549   1592720 59112 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S me.twrp.twrpapp
root      8508  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/7:1H
root      8550  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/5:1H
u0_a232   8611  549   2239816 37316 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.pace.octaproccesorbooster
root      9152  2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/6:1H
u0_a210   10197 550   1706604 43096 SyS_epoll_ 00ef9c37bc S io.rong.push
u0_a210   10259 550   1739448 60852 SyS_epoll_ 00ef9c37bc S com.groundhog.multiplayermaster:Jpush
u0_a128   11118 549   1605876 49956 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S org.kustom.widget.service
u0_a210   14239 550   1738424 51476 SyS_epoll_ 00ef9c37bc S com.groundhog.multiplayermaster
u0_a210   14313 550   1712160 44940 SyS_epoll_ 00ef9c37bc S com.groundhog.multiplayermaster:ipc
u0_a72    14670 549   1588524 39548 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.google.process.gapps
u0_a161   15263 550   1411620 115856 SyS_epoll_ 00ef9c37bc S org.chromium.chrome
root      15684 2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/3:3
u0_a161   16086 550   1118540 54232 SyS_epoll_ 00ef9c37bc S org.chromium.chrome:privileged_process0
root      27050 2     0      0     irq_thread 0000000000 S irq/606-f98a490
u0_a147   27122 550   1033376 39388 SyS_epoll_ 00ef9c37bc S com.estrongs.android.pop.pro
u0_a147   27168 27122 4496   972   skb_recv_d 00efbe671c S /data/user/0/com.estrongs.android.pop.pro/files/libestool2.so
u0_a78    27382 549   1664212 57492 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.android.vending
u0_a112   28797 549   2307352 75680 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.google.android.apps.photos
root      30709 2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/2:1
root      31145 2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 R kworker/u16:1
root      31801 2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/1:1
root      32058 2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/6:1
root      32061 2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/4:1
root      32071 2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/5:2
root      32111 2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/7:0
root      32123 1     1336   20    inet_csk_a 00000f018c S httpd
root      32395 2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/3:1
u0_a112   32501 549   2264712 45432 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S com.google.android.apps.photos:CameraShortcut
u0_a10    32521 549   1582132 38392 SyS_epoll_ 72f4d60d54 S android.process.media
root      32542 2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/u17:2
root      32701 2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/u16:5
root      32708 2     0      0     worker_thr 0000000000 S kworker/3:0
angler:/ #
```

Comment: can you run `ps` and show the output?

Comment: @MarkYisri I can't post it all. The output is too long. I will try to cut out what seems unimportant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
root      32123 1     1336   20    inet_csk_a 00000f018c S httpd
```

That second column is the process ID.  Run this:

```
kill -9 32123
```

For future use, or for other people, get the processes PID with:
`pidof httpd`